# ftp uploader or just a simple uploader

Tags: ftp, jquery, file-upload

I would like to have an uploader something along the lines of [this](http://www.net2ftp.com/) but I want to have a progress bar and e-mail me a notification once it's done like yousendit does it.

Any opensource stuff would be cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) allows a progress bar. As for e-mail notification, you would have to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: looks good.. thank you, I am just worried about glitch and fixes that hasn't been taken care off in the forum.. my programming skill really is not that good..